# How does this improper integral behave?

Tags: calculus

Does the improper integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x^{2\cos^2x}+x^{2\sin^2x}}\,dx$$ converge or does the one diverge?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk Sorry the previous comment should read: Note that
$$\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{x^{2\cos^2(x)} + x^{2\sin^2(x)}} < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\int_{n\pi}^{n\pi+\pi/4}\dfrac{dx}{x^{2\cos^2(x)}} + \int_{n\pi+\pi/4}^{n\pi+3\pi/4}\dfrac{dx}{x^{2\sin^2(x)}} + \int_{n\pi+3\pi/4}^{(n+1)\pi}\dfrac{dx}{x^{2\cos^2(x)}}\right)<\infty$$

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici: I tried $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$ without any success.

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk Each of the integrand is of the form $\frac1{x^a}$, where $a$ ranges between $1$ and $2$ in a continuous fashion. This guarantees that the integrals converge, since the set over which $a$ is close to $1$ can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Leslie Faulkner: You wrote "This guarantees that the integrals converge, since the set over which a is close to 1 can be made arbitrarily small".That statement should be based.

Comment: The integral diverges. The proof can been at [MaplePrimes](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/200780-What-Is-The-Integral).